# Different exceptions happened when running Keras and scikit-learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

I try to pass a Keras model (as a function) to KerasClassifier wrapper from scikit_learn, and then use GridSearchCV to create some settings, and finally fit the train and test datasets (both are numpy array)

I then, with the same python script, got **different exceptions**, some of them are:

_1.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mnist_flat_imac.py", line
>   63, in 
>       grid_result = validator.fit(train_images, train_labels)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py",
>   line 626, in fit
>       base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py",
>   line 62, in clone
>       new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py",
>   line 53, in clone
>
> ***snipped here***
>
> in _deepcopy_dict
>       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 174,
>   in deepcopy
>       rv = reductor(4) TypeError: can't pickle SwigPyObject objects Exception ignored in: > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/c_api_util.py",
>   line 52, in __del__
>       c_api.TF_DeleteGraph(self.graph) AttributeError: 'ScopedTFGraph' object has no attribute 'graph'

_2.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mnist_flat_imac.py", line
>   63, in 
>       grid_result = validator.fit(train_images, train_labels)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py",
>   line 626, in fit
>       base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py",
>   line 62, in clone
>       new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py",
>   line 53, in clone
>       return copy.deepcopy(estimator)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182,
>   in deepcopy
>       y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297,
>   in _reconstruct
>
> ***snipped here***
>
> in deepcopy
>       y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297,
>   in _reconstruct
>       state = deepcopy(state, memo)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155,
>   in deepcopy
>       y = copier(x, memo)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243,
>   in _deepcopy_dict
>       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 174,
>   in deepcopy
>       rv = reductor(4) TypeError: can't pickle SwigPyObject objects

_3.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mnist_flat_imac.py", line
>   63, in 
>       grid_result = validator.fit(train_images, train_labels)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py",
>   line 626, in fit
>       base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py",
>   line 62, in clone
>       new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py",
>   line 53, in clone
>
> ***snipped here***
>
> in _deepcopy_dict
>       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182,
>   in deepcopy
>       y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)   File "/home/longnv/PYTHON_ENV/DataScience/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 306,
>   in _reconstruct
>       y.**dict**.update(state) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Why did it output different errors with the same python script? 
And how can I fix this?

Thank you so much!

P.S.

- python: 3.5
- tensorflow: 1.10.1
- pandas: 0.23.4
- Ubuntu: 4.4.0-124-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

It should be:
clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model)

Instead of:
clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model())